# parsing strings using either grep,awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with lines like below

```
17:59:49.987 - JobID 864563: Found 7 clips from SeqID 862753
17:59:49.987 - Processing Job 864562
17:59:50.003 - JobID 864561: Location 14695 applied clip data successfully. Updating OCAMT_GM_Sent
17:59:50.003 - Processing Job 864563
17:59:50.003 - JobID 864564
17:59:50.018 - JobID 864565
17:59:50.034 - Processing Job 864565
17:59:50.034 - JobID 864566
17:59:50.034 - JobID 864562
17:59:50.034 - JobID 864563
17:59:50.034 - Processing Job 864566
17:59:50.049 - JobID 864567
17:59:50.049 - JobID 864564
17:59:50.049 - Trying to send JobID 864566 to location 14623 at http://172.28.48.11/yb/ClipData.php. Retry count 0
17:59:50.049 - Processing Job 864567
```

I would like to capture certain strings so that its output file is something like below;

```
864563 17:59:49.987
864562 17:59:49.987
864561 17:59:50.003
864563 17:59:50.003
```

Since the the job id length is variable I am thinking of using regular expression \d+ and breaking the line in half using the word Job as a field separator but I am unsure if the following can be combined;

```
awk -F'Job*' '{print $1}'|awk '{print $1}'
awk -F'Job*' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: [edit] your question so the expected output shown is output you'd get from the sample input shown, not output from some different input set. We need something we can test a potential solution against to see if it produces the expected output.

Comment: @Ed i think my sample output file mentioned have the values that can be stripped from the input. i am having problems disregarding the other strings from the input file

Comment: @Dren, on what basis do you want the output.. both Job and JobID or only one of them.. will every line of input contain that keyword?

Comment: @Dren I've no idea what that comment means but just look at the input and output files you provided. None of the values in your output file appear in your input file. Are we supposed to write a script that just makes up numbers and prints them? It's extremely important that the expected output you post is **precisely** the output you should expect from the input you posted, otherwise the example isn't nearly as useful in clarifying your requirements and we have nothing to test a potential solution against since we don't KNOW if what it outputs when run on posted input is what you'd want.

Comment: @Ed sorry my mistake i edited my output. but the logic of the question is taking the time stamp and job numbers from the input file.

Comment: @Dren I posted an answer with sed that will do what you want.

Comment: @Dren no problem, we're getting there. [edit] it again now to explain how you are selecting which timestamps or jobIds to print since they don't all appear in your expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sed** version:

```
sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\).*Job\(ID\)\? \([0-9]\+\).*/\3 \1/g'
```

or with extended regex as pointed out by @spasic:

```
sed -E 's/^(\S+).*Job(ID)? ([0-9]+).*/\3 \1/'
```

Comment: `Job` or `JobID` can also be specified as `Job\(\|ID\)` .. with extended regex, `sed -E 's/^(\S+).*Job(|ID) ([0-9]+).*/\3 \1/'`

Comment: `Job` or `JobID` is written `Job(ID)?`. What you have, `Job(|ID)`, is undefined behavior per the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03) ("**A vertical-line appearing** first or last in an ERE, or **immediately following** a vertical-line or **a left-parenthesis**, or immediately preceding a right-parenthesis, **produces undefined results.**).

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks, didn't know that.. `Job(ID)?` is cleaner as well

Comment: @Dawid, can you update the answer to `Job(ID)?` instead of `Job(|ID)`

Comment: @spasic I already did that yesterday. Didn't know about that either.

Answer (score 3):

from your comments, i assume your are expecting something like this

using `awk`

```
awk -F'[ ]+-.*Job(ID)? |:[ ]+|[ ]+' '{print $2, $1}' file
```

Output:

```
864563 17:59:49.987
864562 17:59:49.987
864561 17:59:50.003
864563 17:59:50.003
864564 17:59:50.003
864565 17:59:50.018
864565 17:59:50.034
864566 17:59:50.034
864562 17:59:50.034
864563 17:59:50.034
864566 17:59:50.034
864567 17:59:50.049
864564 17:59:50.049
864566 17:59:50.049
864567 17:59:50.049
```

Comment: IMO `Job[ID]*` should be changed to `Job(ID)? `